# Appending key value pairs to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need an array of key value pairs. How do I append key value in an array inside a for loop.

```
  array_of_countries = {};
  country_data.features.forEach(each_country => { 
    array_of_countries.id = each_country.id;
    array_of_countries.country_name = each_country.properties.name;
        });
  console.log("array of countries", array_of_countries)
```

This code only gives the last country id and name. I would like to know how to append values in this case. I get the answer as "push" but I am not sure how to use "push" for inserting a key and value. Please help !

Comment: You should use camel case and remove all your underscores when you’re dealing with JavaScript..

Comment: @ahbon snake_case vs camelCase is purely preferential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` is an object, not an array. An array is created by `[]`. What you want to do is done using `map`

```js
const countryData = {features: [{id: 1, properties: {name: 'Foo'}}, {id: 2, properties: {name: 'Bar'}}]};

const countries = countryData.features.map(({id, properties}) => ({id, name: properties.name}));
console.log(countries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need `Array.prototype.push` for this. Also as you asked for a key-value pair, I assume you want the `id` to be the key and the `properties.name` to be the value.

```
let arrayOfCountries = [];
countryData.features.forEach(country => {
  arrayOfCountries.push({ 
    [country.id]: country.properties.name;
});
console.log(arrayOfCountries);
```